# Why does my inner join take longer in MySQL than selecting both tables and joining in Python?

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x, pandas, pandasql

I'm trying to create an efficient MySQL query which includes one inner join, however it is taking a very long time to run. Currently, if I select * on both tables, and join them together using pd.merge in pandas, it is significantly quicker than running the inner join in MySQL.

```py
q = '''
SELECT
    hr.date,
    hr.col2
    df.col3,
    df.col4
FROM
    table1 hr
INNER JOIN 
    table2 df ON
    DATE(df.date) = DATE(hr.date) AND
    df.name = hr.name
WHERE
    hr.date >= "2017-09-01" AND
    LOWER(hr.state) IN ('nsw', 'vic', 'qld', 'wa', 'sa', 'tas', 'nt', 'act')
;
'''

data = pd.read_sql(q, con)
```

I have tried using indexes like suggested in other posts, but this hasn't helped. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: You use a function in your join condition ```DATE(df.date) = DATE(hr.date)```. So even if you have indexed these fields, theses indices won't be used to match the values. Can't you rid of these ```DATE(...)``` ? Idem for the ```LOWER(hr.state)``` (but this one may have less impact).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Turns out I didn't need the date function, and when I removed it the query took ~45seconds.